# Customized Work Emails and Signatures with Each Firm, perhaps with Mutt and Procmail to look Professional?

Tags: email, mutt, procmail

CompanyA sends mail, I want to respond to them with `me@companyA.com` and signatureA. When CompanyB sends mail, I want to respond to them with `me@companyB.com` and signature B. Etc.

```
1. How can I do a hook to change the line `set from="me@CompanyX.com" in .muttrc?

2. How can I -- change the signature according to the sender A, B, C, etc?
```

If someone has a similar problem of having many work -emails that you forward to your server to manage, please, provide me details how you manage this kind of activity. I use mutt, procmail and I have full-blown *ix servers if needing something special.

Answer (score 4):

You can acheive both your goals with `mutt`.

To respond to CompanyA from your `me@companyA.com` address, you would create a folder for each company, and an accompanying `.rc` file in `.mutt/` - and then call the required file from your `.muttrc`. So, for Company A, you would create `.mutt/companya.muttrc`:

```
set from      = "me@companyA.com"
set mbox      = "+CompanyA/archive"
set record    = "+CompanyA/INBOX.Sent"
set postponed = "+CompanyA/INBOX.Drafts"
```

...and then repeat for B.

And in your `.muttrc`:

```
folder-hook CompanyA/* source ~/.mutt/companya.muttrc
folder-hook CompanyB/* source ~/.mutt/companyb.muttrc
...
# boxes
mailboxes +CompanyA/INBOX +CompanyA/Sent +CompanyA/Drafts +CompanyA/Trash
mailboxes +CompanyB/INBOX +CompanyB/Sent +CompanyB/Drafts +CompanyB/Trash
```

To use the correct signature, depending on who you are responding to, use these hooks in your `muttrc`:

```
# set correct signature
send-hook "~f @companyA.com"  set signature=~/.mutt/A.sig
send-hook "~f @companyB.com"  set signature=~/.mutt/B.sig
```

You could then use keybinds to easily switch between folders:

```
macro index ga       "<change-folder> =CompanyA/INBOX"       "go to Inbox"
macro index gb       "<change-folder> =CompanyB/INBOX"       "go to Inbox"
```

Comment: Could you clarify this point `"and an accompanying .rc file in .mutt/"`?

Comment: Essentially, you are breaking out parts of your config into separate files, to allow you to source the relevant options depending on what folder you are working with. So, for CompanyA, you have a `.mutt/companya.muttrc` and for CompanyB a `.mutt/companyb.muttrc` and an overall `.mutt/muttrc`. See [my mutt setup for how I do it](https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/eeepc/src/7684e94c62e2/.mutt).

Comment: I am confused by hooks. I get now all the time one settings so have to understand them better: `"send-hook "~f @CompanyA.com" some.sig"` and `"folder-hook comp/* source ~/.muttr/something.muttrc"`, investigating. If I send email and if I relpy to email, does it look for sender -email or how does this work in practise? Do I need to specify somehow with which comp info I want to send? Anyway have to read your trial deeper, second...